# help with CRCmapper

Tags: python, networks

I'm using [CRCmapper](https://bitbucket.org/young_computation/crcmapper/overview) on my data. There are several modules in the tool. I've used exactly instructed in the usage.

Commands used:

```
python CRCmapper.py -e MB12_noEncBlack_AllEnhancers.table.txt -b MB12.bam -g HG19 -f hg19-stdChr/ -s MB12_peaks.bed -n MB12 -o MB12/
```

Here is the error I got:

```
Warning: text mode turns off computation of q-values
IDENTIFY TF-TF INTERACTIONS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CRCmapper.py", line 605, in <module>
    main()
  File "CRCmapper.py", line 593, in main
    graph = buildNetwork(projectFolder, projectName, candidateGenes, refseqToNameDict, motifConvertFile)
  File "CRCmapper.py", line 381, in buildNetwork
    target = refseqToNameDict[region[0]]
KeyError: 'AP1'
```

My expertise in python is very basic. I would be grateful if someone take a look at this error and suggest how to fix.

P.S. I contacted authors a long back, I didn't get any response.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that the problem is within the files, are you sure that AP1 is in all your files? It could also be a bug on the software

Comment: Yeah, it exists. For other samples, it is a different motif for different sample. It seems to be a bug in the software but I've no idea. Hope someone here will be able to understand.

Comment: Could you paste the minimal files that reproduce the bug? Maybe you can even propose a change in the repository to fix it

Comment: Yeah, I will prepare an example to reproduce. They haven't enabled the issue creator for their repo.

Comment: Well you can do directly a pull request

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the author of CRCmapper.py wants to extract `sequence_name`, `start`, `stop` columns from `fimo.txt` file. But the code extract `motif_alt_id`, `sequence_name`, `start` columns. So the index of the code should be changed.

`fimo.txt` looks like this:

```
motif_id    motif_alt_id    sequence_name   start   stop    strand  score   p-value q-value matched_sequence
Transfac.V$AP1_02   AP1 NM_003046931|3|95762|152118 2332    3118    -   11.9802 6.49e-05        TGACTCA
```

In line 377-382 of the code:

`line[1]` should be changed to `line[2]`.

```
for line in fimoTable[1:]:
    source = motifDatabaseDict[line[0]]
    region = line[1].split('|')
    target = refseqToNameDict[region[0]]
    location = (region[1], int(region[2]), int(region[3]))
```

In line 391-394 of the code:

`line[2]` should be changed to `line[3]`, `line[3]` should be changed to `line[4]`.

```
    # Count unique motifs
    if (region[1], int(region[2]) + int(line[2]), int(region[2]) + int(line[3])) not in motifDictSE[source]:
        edgeCountDictSE[(source, target)] += 1
        motifDictSE[source].append((region[1], int(region[2]) + int(line[2]), int(region[2]) + int(line[3])))
```

Answer (score 2):

This error came from the fact that  the output of the new fimo version has an additional 'motif_alt_id' column in second position.

CRCmapper has been modified to take this into account. You can find the updated version here: https://bitbucket.org/young_computation/crcmapper/src/master/

P.S.: sorry if we missed you request user1545 and thanks for using CRCmapper!